# How to use ArrayInput to populate data in react-admin list view

Tags: reactjs, bulkinsert, react-admin, react-final-form, react-final-form-arrays

I have a `react-admin` `Create` View that I want to display and populate using `ArrayInput` which however seems to ignore the data of the list.

I tried to load the data with

```
const { data } = useQueryWithStore({
    type: 'getList',
    resource: 'comments',
});
```

and to set the source to it manually, but the `ArrayInput` seems unimpressed by all efforts to feed it some data.

I can iterate through the data array and render `TextFields` and remove buttons accordingly, while leaving the `ArrayInput` for adding new data, but that defeats the purpose and the beautiful interaction with `ArrayInput`. Is there something I'm missing? How should I pass the data for it to work as one would expect? I made a sandbox example for this [HERE](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-admin-advanced-recipes-quick-createpreview-forked-8mp0j?file=/src/comments/CommentList.js)

Comment: Your question is not very clear what exactly is the end result you want to achieve. But something I notice is - you are using a SimpleForm inside a List component. This is totally not the expected usage or behaviour. SimpleForm needs a Create/Edit parent component. And List needs a Datagrid or another iterating show component

Comment: Thank you for your remark. It makes no difference if I use the ArrayInput in create view. The ArrayInput does not seem to work as a input component for the top level of the form, but only for entity relations. The end result should be that I can create entities by utilizing the ArrayInput alone (adding new entities with its "+" button and creating them by saving the form).

Comment: It does work the way it is expected to and it does work on top level. With one form submit you can create only one new entity. What you are looking after is Bulk Create action but you will have to come up with a custom implementation about that one.

Answer (score 0):

For creating multiple rows of the entity with one `form` submit you will need a custom implementation or a work-around.

One of the most esiest ways could be to handle manually the submission of the form and alter the data and send separate requests for each entered entity.

[Here in the docs](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/CreateEdit.html#toolbar) is shown an example how you can pass the `Create` view a custom `toolbar` where you can implement your logic.